# @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations do not work

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have TennisCoach class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

@Component
public class TennisCoach implements Coach {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("randomFortuneService")
    private FortuneService fortuneService;

    public TennisCoach() {
        System.out.println("Inside default constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void doMyStartupStuff() {
        System.out.println("Inside postconstructor");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void doMyFinalStuff() {
        System.out.println("Inside predestroyer");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return fortuneService.getFortune();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        return "Practice your backhand volley";
    }
}
```

And such main class:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AnnotationBeanScopeDemoApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("tennisCoach", Coach.class);

        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyFortune());
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());

        context.close();
    }
}
```

Expected output is:

> Inside default constructor
>
> Inside postconstructor
>
> DailyFortune
>
> Practice your backhand volley
>
> Inside predestroyer

But I get this:

> Inside default constructor
>
> DailyFortune
>
> Practice your backhand volley

It seems like @PostContruct and @PreDestroy annotations do not work correctly. I cannot find the reason of my problem.

Comment: What version? Spring boot?

Comment: Not Spring Boot, just Spring Framework. 5.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use java 9+ then add dependency `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api` (or use java 8).

Or use spring-boot 2 if you using spring-boot 1.

Comment: hmm, that's strange. I used java 7, not Spring Boot just Spring Framework but this dependency helped me. Thank you

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov from which JAR were you importing the annotations before?

Comment: @GeorgeZorikov that's ok, but from which JAR file? It might have been that the JAR file you used wasn't correctly copied inside your application server, along with your artifact.

Comment: @LppEdd I realized the reason... I thought javax was not required to be an explicit dependency and could be import just like java.util etc. It is so embarrassing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Spring might not handle JSR-250 lifecycle annotations by default. Check your **applicationContext.xml** that it has  element:

```
<beans ...
    <context:annotation-config/>
    ....
</beans>
```

that configures Spring to be aware of `@PostConstruct` & `@PrePersist`.

Fo more info see [this article](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-lifecycle-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations/).

Answer (score 3):

From the `Spring Core` documentation, paragraph `1.9.8 - Using @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy`

> Provided that the `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is registered
>   within the Spring `ApplicationContext`, a method carrying one of these
>   annotations is invoked at the same point in the lifecycle as the
>   corresponding Spring lifecycle interface method or explicitly declared
>   callback method.

Declaring

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

inside you `applicationContext.xml` file, implicitly register a `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Otherwise, you need to manually register it, using ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html))

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Spring don't know about annotation's @PostContruct and @PreDestroy. 
Add this code in your applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Or implements InitializingBean,DisposableBean interfaces in your TenisCoach class.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is unable to import @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy

This happens because of Java 9 and higher.

When using Java 9 and higher, javax.annotation has been removed from its default classpath. 
Solution

1. Download the javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar from

[maven.org](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar)

2. Copy the JAR file to the lib folder of your project

Use the following steps to add it to your Java Build Path.

3. Right-click your project, select Properties
4. On left-hand side, click Java Build Path
5. In top-center of dialog, click Libraries
6. Click Classpath and then Click Add JARs ...
7. Navigate to the JAR file /lib/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
8. Click OK then click Apply and Close

Eclipse will perform a rebuild of your project and it will resolve the related build errors.